# In a Page. How to add a flag that inform last time a list was modified

Tags: 2013, page-layout, date-time

I have a custom page like this :

```
These are my links (refresh once a day. Last refresh time : **XXXXX** )

link1
link2
link3
```

And I have a custom list.

I want to add "last modified time" or "modified X mins ago" instead of "XXXXX" of the custom list in my page. Is that possible ? Might be easy for advanced dev, but I can't find what to googled.

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/04/14/using-the-javascript-object-model-in-a-content-editor-web-part.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee552819.aspx). So I tried to add JS via embedded code in my page :

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
var siteUrl = "http://mysite/mysubsite";
var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('MyListName');
var value = SP.List.get_lastItemModifiedDate();
write(value);
</script>
```

But this doesn't return anything. As I'm not a developer, I really don't understand what's going on, Any ideas?

I have to say that I also tried this (I've customized variable as needed) without success :

```
function ReadListItem() {
    siteUrl = "my site Url";
    var listTitle = "NewsList";
    //Get the current client context
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var newsList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();         
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Modified\' Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></Query></View>";')
    this.listItems = newsList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(listItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(ReadListItemSucceeded, ReadListItemFailed);
}

function ReadListItemSucceeded(sender, args) {
    var itemsString = '';
    var enumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
        itemsString += 'Modified On: ' + listItem.get_item('Modified');
    }
    $("#P1").append(itemsString);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Javascript to

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
var siteUrl = "http://mysite/mysubsite";
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
var list = lists.getByTitle("MyListTitle");
ctx.load(list, "LastItemModifiedDate");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        alert(list.get_lastItemModifiedDate());
    },
    function() {}
);
}, 'sp.js');

</script>
```

You need to load what you want in the context object and then execute the query

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Trying this right now. And come back for feedback

Comment: Does not return anything. We agree that I click on 'modify page' -> 'Insert' -> 'Embedded code' -> Then paste this in the popup, then save and finally reload the page ?

Comment: You mean the webpart ? Process I explained do actually the same, and creates webpart. But I'll give a try. When I save and reload page (I'm using Google chrome) and use "inspect element", and can see an error : "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on line `var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);`. Does this help you ?

Comment: It means that your code executes before the SharePoint javascrips are loaded! Google SP.SOD.executeFunc

Comment: With the ton of your sentence, I guess this is not normal ? I'll google with you gave me.

Comment: There was not meant to be a tone :) But yes it is an often encountered error. Try my updated script that uses SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded to make sure SP.js is loaded before execution.

Comment: I wanted to say that I really appreciate your time @Robert Lindgren. Btw, same error, but on new line now : `var value = SP.List.get_lastItemModifiedDate();` ... Seems like this is a bad po=roperties, right ? But according to links in my post, this is a real properties ... maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: This is exactly what I just tried, because SP.List doesn't exist obviously. The error is now : "Field (or property) has not been initialized, asked or demand has not been executed. May be ask implicitly" (Sorry for my ugly tard). Error seems to be in "sp.runtime.js", not in script itself

Comment: New code again, from my good friend @AnatolyMironov, http://chuvash.eu/2012/09/24/jsom-last-modified-date-of-a-list/

Comment: Thanks, tried, but still an error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" on "ScriptResource.axd". I think there's an error in code : `clientContext` does not exist, I replaced it with `context`, right ? With ScriptResource.axd, I'm really lost  ...

Comment: Odd, the exact code from Anatoly's link above works for me

Comment: You mean the code you posted as an answer ? Just replacing siteUrl and ListName, right ? SP's language is french, that can be a problem ?

Comment: I updated again ;) But yes if in French you must use the french displayname of the list etc

Comment: Ok, I used your updated code. There is now **NO error**, which is a good point. But I can't see anything. I mean the "get_lasItemModifiedDate" and `ctx.load(list, "LastItemModifiedDate");` have not to be traducted ?

Comment: The code with the alert in? It was missing a while ;)

Comment: Really nice, you did it ! with the alert it works great ... i now just need to put this alert as a text in a sentence. Can i just use `write(list.get_lastItemModifiedDate());` ? for the date format, in my researches I saw a lot of stuff talking about it;

Comment: I mean, I want this alert to be a text in my aspx page. I tried ` write();`does not work, and `append()` too. I'll go on with google. Thanks again @RobertLindgren

Comment: You should use something like jQuery('#anElementId').text(ist.get_lastItemModifiedDate());

Comment: Just in case that can be useful for someone, to write it in my page, I insert a <div> with an ID in the aspx page, then I get that div with the ID and i put so text in with `document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = 'MY TEXT'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with JavaScript and the JavaScript Object Model, called JSOM in SharePoint 2013.

Go read this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj163201(v=office.15)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj163201%28v=office.15%29)

Try this:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Execute-a41c49ff

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) { 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); 
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements'); 

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
    camlQuery.set_viewXml( 
        '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +  
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' +  
        '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>' 
    ); 
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery); 

    clientContext.load(collListItem); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),  
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed) 
    );  
} 

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) { 
    var listItemInfo = ''; 
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator(); 

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) { 
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current(); 
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +  
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') +  
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body'); 
    } 

    alert(listItemInfo.toString()); 
} 

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) { 
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +  
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for your comments. I didn't precise that I'm not a developer at all. I can understand a little bit JavaScript, but I don't know how to use it at all. I will have a look at your links, and try understand. I thought I could do that my modifying the .aspx page, and add something like `<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" ...`, no ? According to [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78495/on-sharepoint-2013-how-do-you-show-the-last-modified-date-on-a-page-layout).

Comment: Well this is the best moment to get some development skills :) It's an easy example / exercise to start through. Read the articles, they will help you and have a look at the examples provided in the second link.

Comment: I learned for 4 years Networks and Systems. I used a few of VB, and I'm friendly with scripting (PS, Bash). But never used JS at all ! I'll read your articles (and get headache) and try doing this, thanks. So there is no way to do this by adding something in the .aspx page ?

Comment: Don't worry it's not that hard. You will not get a headache :) You can put the JavaScript into an .aspx page as well. It will be executed as soon as the page is loaded. Just like every other JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your help. JS really scares me. So, i found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185009(v=office.14).aspx). You are telling me that, ine the aspx page, I simply put JS as you give me before, and script is executed ? this is how developers do ?

Comment: Well your link is for 2010. You tagged the question with 2013. So i would suggest you to use the newer pages for getting started with 2013. Of course it isn't done with copy and paste. You will have to use your site url instead of the one in the example. Take care that you pick the right field/fields, in your case "Modified" in the Query.

Comment: Ok. So I create my page. Put the function that returns me the date I want, then I write something and my function ? like I can do a in script ?

Comment: Look at this: http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/29/how-to-insert-custom-javascript-code-in-sharepoint-2013-pages-part-i/ Adding JavaScript is easy ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use CAML Query and following query should bring you last modified item:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = string.Concat(
      @"<OrderBy> 
           <FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /> 
        </OrderBy>");
query.RowLimit = 1;

var myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListTitle");

if (myList != null)
{
   var itemCollection = myList.GetItems(query);

   var result = string.Empty;

   if (itemCollection.Count > 0)
   {
       SPListItem item = itemCollection[0];
       var lastModifiedDate = DateTime.Parse(item["Modified"].ToString());
       TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - lastModifiedDate;
       result = "modified " + span.TotalMinutes + " mins ago";
   }

   // use result
}
```

This should help