# How to show the last modified date on a page layout

Tags: sharepoint-server, page-layout, publishing-page

I am using below code,I have deployed this through a page layout using visual studio and it's working fine in IE but in chrome when page complete its loading date disappears and shows "undefined,undefined",How to fix this?

```
<%@ Page language="C#"   Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="CustomTag_0" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>


    <PublishingWebControls:LastModifiedIndicator runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Hi @vishal goyal, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Modified" runat="server" ControlMode="Display"/>
```

more details on this link : http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2009/06/free-last-modified-bydate-from.html

In the above link, you will be adding a reference to the Assembly "Microsoft.SharePoint" do change the version of it ( as per your current version of SharePoint)

Also have look at this link: [On Sharepoint 2013 how do you show the last modified date on a page layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78495/on-sharepoint-2013-how-do-you-show-the-last-modified-date-on-a-page-layout)

Comment: I have already tried this but its behaving same?

Comment: could you try opening an Incognito window and check the value.?

Comment: I tried that also but it display same?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by borrowing some code from the built-in Page Layout **EnterpriseWiki.aspx**.

If you open this layout in SharePoint Designer you can find the control used to display the "Last modified at [date] by [User]" string at the top of each Wiki page:

```
<SharePoint:FormattedString FormatText="<%$Resources:wss,wikidiff_lastmodifiedby%>" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:FormField id="modifiedFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Modified" runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:UserField id="editorFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Editor" runat="server" />
</SharePoint:FormattedString>
```

Comment: Agree with Chris, adding the control is the way to go.